# After submitting form Redirect to home page by using Django, python with vue axiox

Tags: python, django, vue.js

When user filled form then after submitting form form needs to redirect to another page. I have tried but I am new to vue so, I am not able to understand how to achieve this please help me to achieve this thank you.

*html*

```
<div id="app">
    <form>
        <input type="text" v-model="username">
        <input type="password" v-model="password">
        <input v-on:click.prevent="submitForm" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

</div>
```

*vue.js*

```
<script>

const vms = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#app',
        data: {
          username: null,
          password: null,

          success_msg: "",
          err_msg: "",

        },
        /* submiting post Ad form */
        methods: {
          submitForm: function(){
            axios({
                method : "POST",
                url:"{% url 'submitform' %}", //django path name
                headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': '{{ csrf_token }}',},
                data : {"username":this.username, "password":this.password},//data
              }).then((response) => {
              console.log(
             this.posts.push(response.data);
          });
          },

        },

    });
    Vue.config.productionTip = false


</script>
```

This is my view code to save data into databse.
**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import vue_testing
import json
def submit_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        username = data['username']
        print("username", str(username))
        # password = data['password']
        # print("password", str(password))
        saveform = vue_testing(username=username,
                               )
        saveform.save()
        return redirect("/")
        # if username and password:
        #     response = f"Welcome {username}"
        #     return JsonResponse({"msg":response}, status=201)
        # else:
        #     response = "username or password is empty"
        #     return JsonResponse({"err":response}, status=400)
    return render(request, 'testing_vue.html')
```

Comment: Why are you using axios to do it ? If you need to be redirected after filling the form, maybe it is better to do it without AJAX.

Comment: Actually we are using vue and Django after submitting the form it should redirect to home page but in our case it is not working. So if you have any idea please help me how to achieve this

Comment: What is doing `vue_testing` ?

Comment: Why did you commented out the `return JsonResponse(...)` ?

Comment: **vue_testing** is model name, in **vue_testing** we are storing data.

Comment: **return JsonResponse(.....)**  with in page it will show results. After submiting form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try these modifications :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import vue_testing
import json


def submit_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
      
        if username and password:
            saveform = vue_testing.objects.create(username=username, password=password)
            response = f"Welcome {username}"
            return JsonResponse({"msg": response}, status=201)
        else:
            response = "username or password is empty"
            return JsonResponse({"err": response}, status=400)

    return render(request, 'testing_vue.html')
```

vue.js

```
<script>
const vms = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#app',
        data: {
          username: null,
          password: null,

          success_msg: "",
          err_msg: "",

        },
        /* submiting post Ad form */
        methods: {
          submitForm: function(){
            axios({
                method : "POST",
                url:"{% url 'submitform' %}", //django path name
                headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': '{{ csrf_token }}',},
                data : {"username":this.username, "password":this.password},//data
              }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                window.location.replace('{% url "home" %}')  // Replace home by the name of your home view
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
              });
          },
        },
    });
    Vue.config.productionTip = false
</script>
```